# ping windows machine from remote server

Tags: networking, firewall, ping

I have a cloud remote server which runs ubuntu. From this server I am able to ping my local mac laptop, but unable to ping my windows desktop.

I have tried the following firewall settings on windows:

[image]

File and Private Sharing are enabled.

I also tried both private and public network:

[image]

I am not sure what else I could do to allow my remote linux server to ping my local windows desktop.

Furthermore, I am able to `ping` from the mac laptop to the windows desktop without a problem.
Pinging the remote from both mac and windows also works.

Got a problem after trying `netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt` and I am running cmd.exe as `administrator` :

```
Resetting Compartment Forwarding, OK!
Resetting Compartment, OK!
Resetting Control Protocol, OK!
Resetting Echo Sequence Request, OK!
Resetting Global, OK!
Resetting Interface, OK!
Resetting Anycast Address, OK!
Resetting Multicast Address, OK!
Resetting Unicast Address, OK!
Resetting Neighbor, OK!
Resetting Path, OK!
Resetting Potential, OK!
Resetting Prefix Policy, OK!
Resetting Proxy Neighbor, OK!
Resetting Route, OK!
Resetting Site Prefix, OK!
Resetting Subinterface, OK!
Resetting Wakeup Pattern, OK!
Resetting Resolve Neighbor, OK!
Resetting , OK!
Resetting , OK!
Resetting , OK!
Resetting , OK!
Resetting , failed.
Access is denied.

Resetting , OK!
Resetting , OK!
Resetting , OK!
Resetting , OK!
Resetting , OK!
Resetting , OK!
Resetting , OK!
Restart the computer to complete this action.
```

Comment: I have windows 11

Comment: updated the question , did not work for me. Please check the result of `(1)` thanks

Comment: all i did on firewall is enabling `File and Printer Sharing` as described in the question

Comment: turned firewall off briefly and cannot ping still from my remote server, however i can ping the mac no problem. weird

Comment: I enabled `File and Printer Sharing` under `windows defender firewall with advanced security` Inbound rule

Comment: That is probably not a firewall issue I believe since turning it off doesn't solve the problem

Comment: I think I know my silly mistake, I'm trying to ping from the remote server into the ipv4 address given by the `ipconfig` command in powershell. From the outside world I can only ping my public ip right ? not the internal one correct ?

Comment: @moth yes, after reading all of this I was wondering when someone was going to bring up the obvious. “Cloud” servers have no reach in to your private network unless you’ve got some kind of VPN setup. Private IP addresses aren’t even routable over the internet. Each location can ping the other locations public IP only. And that’s assuming the gateway is responding to pings.

Comment: Assuming all devices were operating on public IPs, I can also see your windows firewall is wrong. You’re allowing ICMP on private, and public networks from the “local subnet” only. But, I think we already established, and it is generally unlikely your devices have public IP addresses assigned.

Comment: Your question is most unclear. To suggest you can ping A, B and Not Windows suggests local network. You were not clear about being remote.

Comment: but the first phrase of my question is `I have a cloud remote server which runs Ubuntu`. I believe this is clear about being remote